# oracle union caluse: what happens if there is a column name mismatch

Tags: sql, oracle

In oracle, when I do:
select table1.col1 from table1 union select table2.col2 from table2

It gives me the union of all records and the name of the result column is col1.

Should not this throw an error instead because of mismatch of column names?

Comment: No... the result set is created from the first select and as long as the "types" match, the result set from the second select is appended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as the column data types are not mismatched, the column names will always come from the first query.  It shouldn't (and, as you've found, doesn't) throw an error.

If the data types are mismatched, even if implicit conversion is possible, you'll generally get an error

```
SQL> /
select 1 a from dual union select '2' from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

SQL> /
select '1' a from dual union select 2 from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression
```

Comment: I don't know about Oracle, but MySQL and Postgresql don't complains about type mismatch as long as there is an non destructive conversion possible. It is maybe a configuration option though.

Comment: @Krtek - Oracle doesn't generally do a data type conversion.  Posting the test case in my answer.

Comment: Why there should not be an error? It is like saying 2 apples + 3 oranges = 5 apples. What am I missing?

Comment: From a set-theoretic standpoint, the name of a column is irrelevant.  It's simply something useful for humans to make sense of the data.  The database doesn't attempt to figure out whether your query makes sense-- it may be perfectly reasonable to have a row with two apples and a row with 3 oranges because your UNION is trying to create a FRUIT view.  Aggregating the numeric data to determine that you have 5 pieces of fruit may or may not be meaningful.  And choosing to use a poor alias for the result may be confusing, but it's not an error.

Comment: In Oracle, is there anyway to enforce column name match? Tracked down a nasty bug where a column in the second query where placed in the wrong order, but the query ran fine...

Answer (score 2):

`union` doesn't care about columns name, it only cares about the number of columns and eventually their type.

Usually, the name of the columns come from the first query in the `union`.